# Replace a multiline string with pattern using sed command

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

I would like to replace a string where the content is multiline. At each end of line, it can be a /n or \r\n, for the indentation, it can be tabulation or spaces, I don't know. I think the best way to find the string is to use pattern and replace it using sed. This is the content of the file :

```
<Element Blabla>        
        A content
        A second content
        A third content
</Element>
<Element TheSearchedElement>        
        A content
        A second content
        A third content
</Element>
<Element Blabla2>        
        A content
        A second content
        A third content
</Element>
```

I want to replace this block :

```
<Element TheSearchedElement>        
        A content
        A second content
        A third content
</Element>
```

By this block :

```
<Element TheSearchedElement>        
        A content
        A second replaced
        A third content
</Element>
```

I think I should create a variable oldPattern which contains the pattern to find and a variable newPattern which contains the new pattern to write.
This is the content of my script :

```
$oldPattern='<Element TheSearchedElement>*A content*A second content*A third*content*</Element>'
$newPattern='<Element TheSearchedElement>/n/tA content/n/tA second replaced/n/tA third*content/n</Element>'
sed -e '/oldPattern/newPattern/' file.conf
```

The problem is I have an error at output :
script.sh: 1: script.sh: =*A content*A second content*A third*content*: not found
script.sh: 2: script.sh: =/n/tA content/n/tA second replaced/n/tA third*content/n: not found
sed: -e expression n°1, char 14: useless chars after command

I hope you will can help me.

Comment: Is that an XML file?

Comment: @Cyrus, no it's an apache configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do a multiline replacement, you just need to restrict your replacement to an address range:

```
sed '/^<Element TheSearchedElement>$/,\@^</Element>@{/second/s/content/repl/; }' input
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but it doesn't works. I haven't an error, just the content of file in output but nothing has been changed.

Comment: @Anonyme: Remove `$`. Your lines contain trailing spaces.

Comment: Ok, now the output shown on terminal is successfully modified but the file himself is not modified, how can I modify directly ? Thanks.

Comment: Create a temporary file and move it.  Or, if you are using gnu sed, you can use `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/<Element TheSearchedElement>/{print;getline;print;getline;print "        A second replaced";next} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into same Input_file itself then do following(if you are happy with above command's results):

```
awk '/<Element TheSearchedElement>/{print;getline;print;getline;print "        A second replaced";next} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

Comment: Hello, thanks it works but I prefere to use command `sed` because If a day, the place of the line to replace in the block changes, the script will not works.